# Create object if not exist Django Rest Viewsets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Моя проблема: Я отправляю запрос с `frontend`, который содержит в себе логин и пароль. И в `Django` мне нужно это проверить, существует ли пользователь с таким логином. И если да, то отправить ошибку, если нет, то создать. И сообщить в любом случае на `frontend`. Как это можно реализовать? И можно будет прочитать ответ на `frontend`.

serializers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):        
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

И мой js файл, где я отправляю запрос:

```
const register = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/', {
            login: loginReg,
            password: passwordReg,
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please translate your question but this is russian community)

Comment: Перевел на русский :)

Comment: Google translate, this is crooked translate. I edit this.

Comment: Я так-то из Беларуси и говорю на русском) Гугл транслейт мне не нужен)

Comment: Ну, кажется что тут гугл переводчик помог.

Comment: То есть нам надо вам view написать?

Comment: Можно и написать. Я не нашел в гугле решений своей проблемы, либо знаний не хватает. И нужна помощь людей, который либо смогут написать эту проверку (это же пара строчек кода), либо укажут на ресурс, где можно найти подобную информацию